# 3D effects description book

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d

I was wondering around google and found nothing good for 3D effects such as bump map, parallax mapping, etc. Please help me with this, is there a book which describes different ways to achieve such effects? furthermore if the book has opengl samples for the algorithms it would be much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **GPU Gems** series of books comes to mind. Also available online at the NVidia developer webside.

Answer (score 4):

I've enjoyed Real-Time Rendering. When I wrote my 3D engine everything I needed to know was contained in that book.
http://www.realtimerendering.com/book.html

Comment: Bingo! just one thing, where is the HDR?

Comment: @Green Code: It's right there, in the third edition of the book.